# How do I get the array of strings of a property as union type (from a json file)?

Tags: typescript

I have this json file:

```json
{
    "ADMIN": [
        "a"
    ],
    "ADMIN_2": [
        "a",
        "b"
    ]
}
```

I'd like to know if it's possible to get all the values of the arrays as a type, a type that would be:

```
type Permission = 'a' | 'b' // and any other values that are in the group of arrays
```

I don't want to define the types, I want it to be inherited from my json file.

Comment: It's in a json file? How do you access that file in TS to begin with?  `import` or something?

Answer (score 0):

*I don't want to define the types, I want it to be inherited from my json file.*

This is currently not possible, but very much popular among the community. Here is a github [thread](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32063)

You can make a different type of file where again you will have to define it types. You might lean towards it since here you do not define the types while importing. [Link](https://www.totaltypescript.com/override-the-type-of-a-json-file).

I will mention the steps here:

1. Create a `.d.json.ts` version of your json file.
2. Declare the types inside that file:

```
declare const data: {
  ADMIN: ['a'];
  ADMIN_2: ['a', 'b'];
};

export default data;
```

Something like the above or whatever typing you prefer.

3. Add `"allowArbitraryExtensions": true` inside the compiler options of your tsconfig.

Now your IDE should be able to detect the type of your son.

Here is the screenshot of my VS code:

[image]